# ListView OnLongClick strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, mobile, onlongclicklistener

I have a ListView within my project. It has many elements, and it uses a custom adapter, since its populated dynamically from a rails server.

I want to change the content of a ListItem when the item is longpressed. In order to achieve this, I have 2 layouts inside the ListItem, with one visible and one hidden.

The issue is that when I longpress an item, the layout changes (As expected), but other ListItems are also affected, and changed in the same way. This appear to occur once for every 5 items, and I cant figure out why.

This is the LongClickListener I'm using, it is located inside de GetView method on the custom adapter:

```
View v = convertView;

if (v == null){
   LayoutInflater vi =
      (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(
         Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}

final LinearLayout placeInfo =
   (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_info);

final RelativeLayout placeBrief =
   (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_brief);

v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

   @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      placeInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      placeBrief.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      return false;
   }});
```

I would appreciate any help, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you intended to long click the entire listview or just an individual item, if so you should be using `setOnItemLongClick()` instead.

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't get it to work. Still, the way I'm doing it changes the layout. Its the side effect (Layout change affects more than 1 ListItem) that I cant work around.

Comment: So what I think you are trying to do is when an item in your listview is long clicked you want to no longer show that item in the list?

If that is the case I can write something up soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListViews recycle Views, so you only have a few views for all of your items. You're directly changing one of these view instances to switch between the info|brief. What you need is to save the status of the info|brief flag for the affected position *somewhere else* (e.g. a list of positions that should be "briefs" in the adapter). That way when you come back into `getView()` you can display the right one.

Comment: I understand the concept. However, how am I supposed to display de right one inside the getView(), based on a list, for example? I can't imagine it.

Comment: The simplest (and not most efficient way) would be to just have an array of booleans that's the size of the list, with a `true` value where the position should be displayed as a brief. But you don't need that much, just a set that contains the indexes that you want (`brief = set.contains(position)`).